# when i compiling eclipse RCP project,I encounter an error; the error is "No git repository found searching upwards "

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, scada

when i build eclipse scada project by maven;why git is part of build process;how to remove it from build process;please look at follow error information

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.22.0:build-qualifier
(default-build-qualifier) on project org.apache.commons.daemon: No git
repository found searching upwards from
K:\scada\SourceCode\org.eclipse.scada.external\org.apache.commons.daemon
-> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Check the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Git is part of the build process in order to generate the build identifier for each OSGi bundle.